# passing string to win32 function with cgo

Tags: go, cgo

I try this

```
name := C.CString("vds")
C.OpenService(scm, (name), C.DWORD(C.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS))
```

but it wont compile

```
.\test.go:28: cannot use name (type *C.char) as type *C.CHAR in argument to _Cfunc_OpenService
```

I tried looking for similar things (sqlite for example) but they seem to use this same idiom, but it compiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try explicitly casting it:

```
name := C.CString("vds")
C.OpenService(scm, (*C.CHAR)(unsafe.Pointer(name)), C>DWORD(C.SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS))
```